# SQL Math function from 2 tables with variables show output in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

can anybody help me with SQL query ?

I have similary this tables

TABLE1:

```
id_table1    ean    date_from      date_to     type     region      consumption 
  1          1234   2020-01-01    2021-01-01   blue      big          20000
  2          5678   2020-01-01    2021-01-01   blue      big2         80000
  2          6845   2020-01-01    2021-01-01   white    small         10000
```

TABLE2:

```
id_table2        day      hour     type_blue_big_coefficient   type_blue_big2_coefficient  type_white_coefficient
  1          2020-01-01     1             0.011120                0.32652                     0.054165
  2          2020-01-01     2             0.023265                0.12543                     0.054165
```

And I need to show output like this:

```
EAN         Day           Hour     consumption  
1234     2020-01-01        1          222.4
5678     2020-01-01        1          26 121.6
6845     2020-01-01        1           541.65
```

Output consumtion is calculated by multiplication of coefficient from table2 and consumption from table1.
There are many variables in calculated by type and region from table1.
In the resulting view I need to show all EAN in TABLE 1 divided by day and hour with consumption for all hours.

Anybody know how to do it ?

///////
UPDATE

Thanks @Gordon Linoff for help. Now I have problem with query speed.
In Table1 is about 40 000 Records and in table2 about 8000 Records

Query runing for a hour without finish.. with few records all working OK.
Tested on 2 servers.
[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a7af515400b1e2acf6c0d459ed61f3f) is link for working query in db

Comment: Decimals in the data set followed by commas in the result set it too confusing. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t1.ean, t1.day, t2.hour,
       sum(case when t1.type = 'blue' and region = 'big' then t2.type_blue_big_coefficient * t1.consumption
                when t1.type = 'blue' and region = 'big2' then t2.type_blue_big2_coefficient * t1.consumption
                when t1.type = 'white' then t2.type_white_coefficient * t1.consumption
                else 0
           end) as consumption                
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ean = t2.ean and t1.day = t2.day
group by t1.ean, t1.day, t2.hour;
```

You should really fix your data model.  Storing the coefficient values in separate columns in `table2` is an anti-pattern.  Those should really be in separate rows, so you can just join the tables together on the appropriate keys.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9544bf4e7b9b7b5700e23bc14bd69169) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yes, something like that. But t1.day doesnt exist because in Table 1 is date selected between 2 rows. Table2 is okey there is only one date pattern for select. I must work with these data because this data is from one software where we cannot change output.

I try your SQL query but Mysql show 0 rows.

Comment: @MilanLidmila . . . I see that I misread the data model the first time around.  I fixed the answer and added a fiddle.

Comment: thanks for help. Your query work great. But after I update it for use in my database query still no output but query looks OK.. link to db<>fiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3d9ce6bd46c39c3435ef5488f957f67)

Comment: sorry.. I have bad date format in database. 

I have one more question. How to sum this selected coefficient between days from _POST variable before multiplication with the consumption in the given time range?